# Recurly vs SaaS Kit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, e-commerce, payment-gateway, payment, saas

From some reading and input from a couple of seasoned developers, it appears that I'm down to a choice between Recurly and RailsKits.com SaaS Kit.  I'm hopeful to get some broader experiences from folks in the community here as to the pros and cons perhaps you've experienced.

***I'd really like to be sure that I put together an apples-to-apples comparison here.***

First, I'm offering a service that has two subscription levels of about $1 and $5 / month recurring.  These may be paid in either monthly, yearly or every three years (get some discounts at the longer subscription levels).  I obviously need to keep transactional costs as low as possible, but I need to maintain this and be sure that recurring billing is reliable and not problematic.

I'll be building this atop Rails 3.

The bag seems mixed as you get a more robust admin feature set it seems with Recurly, yet I may be able to save enough with a SaaS Kit + (for example) https://merchant-apply.com/tesly to make it worth it.

I have reviewed Chargify vs Recurly and Recurly seems to be the winner for my particular model and so that's why I've kinda eliminated many other options at this point.

If you've faced this before, what has worked for you or do you have some practical input in this regard?

Comment: My input: don't put your billing in the hands of some random 20-somethings at a startup. Recurly users have been burned before, when they increased prices by several orders of magnitude on their beta users; it can happen again. You may want to stop paying someone else to do a bad job at managing your subscriptions, but you can't easily switch because they have all your customers' billing info, not you. The moment you close your account your revenue goes to $0, and there's no way 100% of your customers will fill out another form to sign up with your new billing method.

Comment: What of the liability factor? Is it not serious risk to collect all of this ourselves?  Perhaps then I should not discount Chargify as it supposedly allows exportation or transference of this information.  What are your thoughts in this regard and therefore making absolute sure that we're safe even if we do go the SaaS Kit path?

Comment: Recurly supports the Credit Card Data Portability Standard (blog.recurly.com/2010/05/credit-card-portability), which means that you own your customer credit card data. If you choose to move from Recurly - the data is yours and will be transferred to another PCI compliant vendor. Because Recurly stores your customer data (rather than with the gateway), you can also easily transfer your business to other payment gateways.

The PCI compliance requirements are very strict when storing credit card data yourself. Check https://www.pcisecuritystandards.org/ for more details about what is required.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I work at Recurly, so I'll try to not make this a sales pitch :)

As I noted in the comments above, PCI compliance can be tricky, time-consuming, and expensive, so please check each product and see what is required for your business. You can see documentation on Recurly's PCI compliance requirements at http://docs.recurly.com/security/pci-compliance/. SaaS Kit reduces some elements of PCI compliance by storing the payment information with the gateway, but this means you cannot easily switch payment gateways - most gateways will not allow you to take your data with you. If you choose to use Authorize.net's CIM service with SaaS Kit, this will be an additional $20/month gateway fee for the credit card storage.

I also recommend you take a look at the API docs of each product. Depending on your integration complexity with Recurly, some merchants never need to work with the API (instead using hosted checkout pages and the admin virtual console inside Recurly), but other merchants will have a more complex billing scenario that involves use of the API. The docs for each product should give you a good idea of how easy they will be to work with.

I'd be happy to answer any questions you have as you continue to look!

Comment: Well Rachel, thanks for the offer and catching the posts.  It's useful to get some more clarity.  On the PCI compliance that can be done. It is expensive. I would like to take you up on one thing that is not clear, which is a complete price breakdown matrix. Could you explain given our scenario above where every cost per transaction comes out and to whom it goes and at the end of the sieve what we're, the service provide and Recurly customer, is left with? One thing that was not clear is whether we need an additional gateway service and if so let's plug the most cost effective one here.

Comment: Certainly! Recurly works on top of a payment gateway and merchant account, so those fees will be *in addition to* Recurly. Recurly pricing tiers are based on your volume, so if you're doing 200 or fewer transactions per month it's $69 plus $.10/transaction (a transaction is a successful purchase or refund.

Comment: Gateways have their own fee structures. If you're in the US, PayPal typically tends to be the cheapest for smaller/new merchants. They have a gateway + merchant account product that is very popular. I also like Intuit Merchant Services because they tend to be very affordable, also have a gateway + merchant account product, and their support for Recurly customers is top-notch (we have a dedicated rep there).

Comment: Finally, given the above scenario, a customer paying monthly would cost you $.10 a month through Recurly (plus the monthly base fee). Your gateway/merchant account would charge additional fees for processing the payment. A customer who is paying yearly would only cost you $.10 a year through Recurly (plus your monthly base fees), and then the individual gateway/merchant account fees.

Comment: Can you give me an idea of common gateway costs.  Let's use Intuit's since you mention it. I've looked at several, but I think this is worth the effort to see it from your eyes.  There's a good chance that ~40% of clients will be paying month to month & so the steeper dipping for these micro payments is not terribly fun. Example, we're looking at on the ~1000 transaction mark about 29¢ coming out for Recurly.  Also, on your transactions, pls explain, are those transactions / month or cumulative transactions? Ie, we have 1500 come aboard 1st month and 200 next, does it reset or are we at 1700?

Comment: I can't give you a good estimate of gateway costs, as they will vary by merchant. For Intuit, I recommend giving them a call at (888) 692-3621 - if you tell them a bit about your business, they can quote you some figures.

Comment: Recurly's transaction count is only based on your current monthly volume. In the first month you'd be charged 29¢ x 1500 (because you charged 1,500 subscribers through Recurly). In the next month, you'd be charged 29¢ x 1700 **if** all of these subscribers are paying monthly (because you'd then again be processing payment for each of those customers in the next month). If a customer is paying yearly, they're only counted as a transaction for the month payment is actually processed.